# Highcharts - Changing color of text if not enough room on bar graph

Tags: highcharts

I'm currently using a bar graph to display my data. In this div, my bar graph is sitting at 50% width. If the percentage of the bar is too large for the width, the text next to the bar that displays the percentage such as 10% shows in the bar graph itself. Which is fine, but with the using the same color css as the bar graph. In this situation it is hard to read the percentage.

I would like the percentage to use the same color as the bar graph but Is it possible to change the text to white only when this happens?

Here is a photo example:

[image: https://i.ibb.co/tZwvmzr/image.png]

Here is a code snippet of what i'm using to change the color of the text using `plotOptions`

```
  plotOptions: {
    bar: {
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        formatter: function() {
          return ` <span style="color:${this.color};">${this.y} %</span>`;
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

Here is a link to my jsfiddle where the issue is re-created: https://jsfiddle.net/8g4uL0jm/22/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that a better idea will be to change the dataLabels color after their initializing, which gives us information about their positions.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/af02bgs7/

```
events: {
    load() {
        let chart = this;
        
        chart.series[0].points.forEach(p => {
            if (p.dataLabel.alignOptions.align !== "right") {
                p.dataLabel.css({
                    color: p.color
                })
            }
        })
    }
}
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load

Comment: @Sebestian Thank you for your response, It does achieve what I am attempting to but it does remove the text color of the percentages that don't have the position issue. Is there a way to achieve both? If the text is not inside of the bar, have the color be the color of the bar like the original, if the text is inside the bar, make white. At the moment in the jsfiddle link you provided, all other text colors are black

Comment: @stepheniok changing the `load` callback into the `render` callback should change it. Check the demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qgpd1xuf/